# Problems with ACID / BASE interface for SNORT IDS on remote host

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, https, snort, forbidden

I've just installed SNORT and ACID/BASE following this step by step tutorial: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SnortIDS on a remote Debian host over SSH. The main difference being that I have already setup a firewall that fillers all incoming traffic except for SSH, HTTPS and loopback.

Now when I try to access https ://domain.xx/acidbase/base_db_setup.php , i.e. acidbase's front end in the final configuration step I get the following error:
**403 FORBIDDEN**
`You don't have permission to access /acidbase/base_db_setup.php on this server.`

I have already run this command:
`sudo sed -i "s#allow\ from\ 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0#allow\ from\ 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0\ 10.10.1.10/255.255.255.0 my-vpn-gateway.xx#" /etc/acidbase/apache.conf`
and restarted Apache.

I also tried to access the URL from within my SSH session via Lynx web browser but whenever I type: https ://localhost/ it tells me:
`Unable to make secure connection to remote host.`
However when I type: https ://mydomain.xx/ it works. So maybe I also have some bug in my Apache configuration.

The remote host is running an Apache 2.2 web server, and I disabled the VirtualHost on port 80 and left only the one for port 443.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally discovered the problem. It was actually an Apache configuration problem. All I had to do is add back:
`NameVirtualHost *:80

 Listen 80`
To my ports.conf file and restart Apache. I had initially removed them before setting up the Firewall to restrict the access to HTTPS only. After this I managed to access http://localhost from the Lynx web browser within my SSH session.